# Sending an InputStream thru akka-http

Tags: java, akka

I need to send a java.io.InputStream through akka http and am a loss as to how to do this... I have something like

```
HttpRequest.POST(buildURL(path, params))
            .withEntity(HttpEntities.create(ContentTypes.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM, streamAsSource(inputStream))).withHeaders(m_headers))
```

and trying to implement streamAsSource... Can an InputStream even be an entity? Is there any examples of this?

Answer (score 1):

StreamConverters.fromInputStream(() -> inputStream))

apparently looks like the answer.